# way to increment a separate counter inside of a angular ngfor loop based on condition

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have a *ngFor loop that I need increment a customCounterHERE variable based on the element from the loop and a specific condition. Thus this customCounter variable will be different than the index of that loop.

I have read about custom attribute directives but I am not sure if this is what I need and how to use it. Any ideas and solutions would be very helpful!

```
<tr *ngFor="let diff of cardList[i].Relations;">
  <td>{{diff.relationName | titlecase}}</td>
  <td>{{diff.relationType | titlecase}}</td>
  <td>{{diff.operation | titlecase}}</td>
  <td *ngIf="diff.relationName !== 'Contains'  && diff.relationName !== 'Houses' ">. 
    {{diff.name | titlecase}} 
  </td>
  <td *ngIf="diff.relationName === 'Contains' || diff.relationName === 'Houses'; " 
    style="color:black 
    (click)="showMoeFunc(i);toggleNestedDiff(i,customCounterHERE);"
  >
  <div style="display:flex" >
    <span>{{diff.name | titlecase}}</span>
    <button *ngIf="!showNested[i][customCounter]">
      <mat-icon class="hide-diff"[ngClass]="!showNested[i][customCounterHERE]?'hide- 
      diff':'rotateArrow hide-diff'"
      >
        arrow_right</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <button *ngIf="showNested[i][customCounterHERE]">
      <mat-icon class="hide-diff"[ngClass]="showNested[I] 
        [customCounterHERE]?'rotateArrow hide-diff':'hide-diff'"
      >
       arrow_right
      </mat-icon>
    </button>
  </div>
 </td>
 <td>{{diff.currentValue === '' ? '---' : diff.currentValue}}</td>
 <td>{{diff.newValue === '' ? '---' : diff.newValue}}</td>
</tr>
```

If the diff.relationName === 'Contains' I want to increment the customCounterHere and pass it functions and specific places where it's necessary.

Comment: someone might have a better solution for you, but I find it's best for these types of situations to iterate through the array once in javascript and set flags on the data, and then use the results of that in your ngFor loop, using the flags to display things properly.

Comment: That's an idea. I'll think about an alternative solution.

Comment: The issue is that from the HTML I need to know which element from the loop was clicked on so I can toggle the appropriate a boolean value in an array I have.

Comment: By custom attribute do you mean **directive**? I think you are trying to put too much business logic in your template. Have a look at **directives** which will pass down your bound data, there you can handle the logic.

Comment: yes I do attribute directive.

Comment: something like what @Rick is suggesting is the correct way to go about this. Right now, your model isn't sufficient for your view, so you need to augment your model. Though, getting even higher level, it' likely whatever is being done in those `toggleNestedDiff` and `showMoeFunc` functions could be improved to not require this at all.

Comment: I concede based on all of your statements Rick, godhar ,@bryan60. Thanks for your feedback. I may delete this post because I believe using the index on the for loop will work because the only time the user can click the table cell is when the condition is true so I can get the index I am looking for in my array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are overcomplicating your logic. if you are stepping through an array using:

```
*ngFor="let diff of cardList[i].Relations;"
```

then you should be able to handle any counters by attaching them to the diff item:

```
(click)="diff.customCounter++"
```

and then use that in your logic:

```
[ngClass]="showNested[i][diff.customCounter]?...
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your answer. I think this is the insight I needed to implement the toggle event I want.